# LSTM for 1D input - TensorFlow Exception

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, keras, lstm

i'm working on a 2-layer RNN (LSTM). I think i have successfully reshaped my train and test set but when i try to run the code, it stops with the Exception:

> Exception: When using TensorFlow, you should define explicitly the
>   number of timesteps of your sequences. If your first layer is an
>   Embedding, make sure to pass it an "input_length" argument. Otherwise,
>   make sure the first layer has an "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape"
>   argument, including the time axis.

I tried several configuration, but no one works well. I don't know how to fix it..

Here it is the code where i create the model and reshape X_train and X_test

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], EMB_SIZE))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], EMB_SIZE))


print 'Building model...'

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(input_dim=EMB_SIZE, output_dim=100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(input_dim=EMB_SIZE, output_dim=100, return_sequences=False,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, 
          Y_train, 
          nb_epoch=5, 
          batch_size = 128, 
          verbose=1, 
          validation_split=0.1)


score= model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=128)
print score
```

any help is really appreciated!

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: if i change Keras version (from 0.3.3 --> 2.1.0) it gives me: 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (15015, 1)

Comment: UPDATE: i made it work by putting Dense(1) instead of Dense(2) and updating Keras to 2.1.0.

Sorry if i ask you, but why? Then, if move back to Keras 0.3.3 it gives me the error explained in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of units in the last layer defines the output shape of the model.

The output shape must be the same shape as your targets (Y).

- `Dense(2)` -> Output shape = (None, 2)
- `Dense(1)` -> Output shape = (None, 1)
- `Y_train` -> Target shape = (15015,1)

Whoa.... Keras 0.3.3? No wonder everything will be problematic.

Comment: Great :)) -- When an answer satisfies your question, please mark it as answered :), @OscarMagarini